# Embedded WebRTC as a widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webrtc

I'm trying to build a widget where a user can install my widget with a few lines of javascript, similar to how you install sumome.

```
<script src="//load.sumome.com/" data-sumo-site-id="dcbc359888045cb6458e04e1bac228af193a0ed6b55dd4ee7b84bdfc14376479" async="async"></script>
```

And the widget will be doing get/put requests to my ruby on rails server for the webrtc and additional functions.

Is this even possible to do since i read that jquery does mainly XML GET's.

EDIT: This website https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/05/embedding-webrtc-video-chat-right-into-your-website/ built one (i think?), but it doesn't seem to be functional.

Comment: `i read that jquery does mainly XML GET` jquery uses whatever method you ask it to

Comment: Can you clarify a bit further (im' fairly new to javascript/jquery)? Isn't AJAX the only way to grab information from another server?

Comment: jquery `$.ajax` uses whatever http `method` you need

Comment: `Isn't AJAX the only way to grab information from another server?` - not really, but AJAX isn't restricted to GET so your point is invalid

Comment: I don't think you have a grasp on how webRTC works. It only uses server for a quick hand off before going peer to peer

Comment: @charlietfl - I think that's the point of the widget

Comment: Tons of resources here https://webrtc.org/

Comment: @charlietfl so that would mean that there shouldn't be of any need to do any sort of GET requests for the WebRTC, right? The widget would just need to create and show a room with a specific id so the peers can join the same room. (the widget would be shown on other peoples website. I know that's obvious, but  i figured i should state it just in case).

Comment: @Raidspec basically yes . All the data then gets passed between peers.

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the quick responses! One last question for you (if you don't mind) before I go start watching a row of videos on webrtc.org. I've noticed that there's a lot of webrtc providers that lets you use their api/sdk (pubnub, opentok, twilio, ect) to put webrtc on your own website. Is this normal for people who wants to build their own webrtc?

Comment: I've never actually used it but have been through a bunch of those videos doing some research. I would go for one of those services for sure. PubNub for example is a huge enterprise. You could have the basics wired up and working in a couple of hours doing it that way

Comment: @charlietfl yeah i guess it would be the fastest way to build the webrtc. Just feels weird promoting my product as a SAAS to other websites when I'm using someone else's API in my product to run my webrtc servers. Actually...that's probably common for a lot of products.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue is to open the widget in an iframe. See

[rtchub.com](https://rtchub.com) as an example